# Are there PnP RPGs based on Moorcock's "non-Elric" works?

Tags: game-recommendation

As the title of the Q says.

Are there any PnP RPGs based on those works of Michael Moorcock whose (anti)hero is not Elric?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [the Hawkmoon RPG](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/12/12138.phtml).  Chaosium planned to do a whole Eternal Champion series but Stormbringer (Elric) and Hawkmoon (Dorian Hawkmoon) were the only two that hit. They have been [made available again in PDF](http://www.rpgnow.com/index.php?cPath=5618) courtesy of Chaosium and Mongoose. Mongoose had said they were working on a RQII version of Hawkmoon and Corum but it doesn't appear that they ever appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Not complete RPGs, but there are two supplements for the Chaosium Elric RPG by Darcsyde Publications.  The [Hawkmoon RPG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0933635311), based on the same rules set employed in their versions of Runequest and Call of Cthulhu.  RPG.Net has a [review](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/12/12138.phtml) on the system if you're interested in reading about it. There was also a supplement for the old Chaosium Elric Game for [Corum](http://www.darcsyde.org./Corum/index.html) published by the same company.